# ggplot 2, how to factorize in stat summary?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

In this image, I show what the data file looks like (the actual numbers are slightly different, but just to show how the data is setup). I am trying to get my graph to look exactly like this one

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2s4E.png

I am simply trying to reproduce the graph, however how can I get a mean plotted for when dminp is -3 to -1 with dmin -1 to 1, dminp is -3 to 1 with dmin 1 to 3, and the same goes for when dminp is -1 to 1. So I should have 4 points on my graph total as shown in the photo.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes (x = factor(dminp), y = sum_diff, group = dmin))+
stat_summary(geom = "point",fun.y = "mean", col = "black",size = 5, shape = 8)+
stat_summary(geom = "point", fun.y = "mean", col = "red", size = 5, shape = 6)
```

This is what i have (i know this isnt correct, but how can i do this? or do i need to change the data format first?)

Comment: please provide some sample data in order to make an reproducible example

Comment: The data is in the image.

Comment: Data in pictures isn't very useful - it's very hard for people to run code on it to demonstrate a solution. Please provide data in valid R syntax. `dput()` is a very nice function for this, `dput(df[1:8, ])` gives a copy/pasteable version of the first 8 rows of data. Just type that in your console, and put the result into your question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on comments, providing data as an image is not really useful as people can't copy/paste on it to try some code to help you.

Your error is that you are trying to set the shape and the color for each group inside `stat_summary` instead of using `scale_color_manual` and `scale_shape_manual`.

Here, I create a fake dummy dataset:

```r
dminp = c("A","B","A","A","B","A","B")
dmin = c("C","D","D","C","C","C","D")
val = c(0.03, 0.07, 0.05, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.01)

df <- data.frame(dminp,dmin, val)
```

Using `stat_summary`, you can do the following:

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes (x = factor(dminp), y = val, shape = dmin, color = dmin))+
  stat_summary(geom = "point",fun.y = "mean",size = 5)+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(8,6))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","red"))
```

[image]

Alternatively, without using `stat_summary`, you can compute the mean outside of `ggplot2` using `dplyr` for example and get the same plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(dminp, dmin) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(val)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = dminp, y = Mean, color = dmin, shape = dmin))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(8,6))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","red"))
```